# How to animate input placeholder position on hover/focus

Tags: jquery, input, onclick, placeholder

On this website: http://www.cinemec.nl/homepage/ they have in the search field right in the corner a placeholder who floats on click.

I want this on my website to but i can't find how to do it, is there a easy way with onclick or something?

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with CSS. The idea being the placeholder `padding` attribute is changed on `:hover` and `:focus` so it moves from left to right. Combined with a CSS `transition` we can animate the movement.

```css
input {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: padding 0.5s;
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: padding 0.5s;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: padding 0.5s;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  -ms-transition: padding 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: padding 0.5s;
}


/*
    * On hover
    */

input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 90px;
}

input:hover:-moz-placeholder,
input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  padding-left: 90px;
}

input:hover::-moz-placeholder,
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  padding-left: 90px;
}

input:hover:-ms-input-placeholder,
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Update coming soon.